# Options Framework options not being output

Tags: theme-options

I am using the Options Framework.

In my theme's `options.php`, I have the following code:

```php
    function optionsframework_options() {
    
        $options = array();
            
        $options[] = array(
            'name' => __('Footer Navigation', 'options_framework_theme'),
            'type' => 'heading');
    
        $options[] = array(
            'name' => __('Button 1 URL', 'options_framework_theme'),
            'desc' => __('Enter the URL clicking on the button takes you to.', 'options_framework_theme'),
            'id' => 'footer-nav1_URL',
            'std' => '',
            'type' => 'text');
            
        $options[] = array(
            'name' => __('Button 1 Text', 'options_framework_theme'),
            'desc' => __('Enter the text you see underneath the button.', 'options_framework_theme'),
            'id' => 'footer-nav1_text',
            'std' => '',
            'type' => 'text');
```

In my theme's `footer.php`, I have the following code:

```php
<?php if (of_get_option('footer-nav1_URL', '') !== '') { ?>
        <a href="<?php echo of_get_option('footer-nav1_URL', '');?>">
            <span id="icon1" class="index2"></span>
            <span class="iconshadow index1"></span>
            <span class="name"><?php echo of_get_option('footer-nav1_text', '');?></span>
        </a>
<?php 
}?>
```

Those options are not being output in the footer. The footer is working normally otherwise.

Other options called in `front-page.php` are working okay though.

Why won't these options work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are using **uppercase** letters in the options *id*:

```
footer-nav1_URL
```

Try instead:

```
footer-nav1_url
```

In general you should avoid using uppercase letters in options names in WordPress.